# Filtering tweets based on both locations and track keywords

Tags: java, twitter4j

I am trying to filter the streaming by location and track words that I know that they are combined with an OR condition.

But, I would like to filter the tweets with an AND condition, such as tweets from a certain location that contain certain tracked words.

Is that possible? Can someone suggest me a way to do this?

Comment: This question doesn't really provide enough detail for someone to be able to help.  Please provide additional detail such as code, things you have tried, resources you've consulted.  Also see here: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. It only works as logical OR.

You can track keywords (don't track location here) and in the statuslistener check the tweets location.

```
public void onStatus(Status status) {
  if(status.getGeoLocation != null) {
    double latitude = status.getGeoLocation.getLatitude();
    double longitude = status.getGeoLocation.getLongitude();
    // use these values
  }
}
```